# Pro Tools Plug-ins

Tags: pro-tools, plug-ins, freeware, mac, osx

Do Pro Tools 8 HD plug-ins work on Pro Tools 8 LE? What Plug-ins will work on Pro Tools 8 LE that you don't get with your Pro Tools LE package that are freeware and acceptable with Mac OSX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi Wesley,

Here are some suggestions of free plug-in that play nice with Pro Tools on a Mac...

FreeG from Sonalkiss
http://www.sonalksis.com/freeg.htm

Mid-Side Suite from reFUSE Software
http://www.refusesoftware.com/products/feature/10

Flipper from reFUSE Software
http://www.refusesoftware.com/products/feature/12

Vinyl from iZotope
http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/vinyl/

BitterSweet 2 from Flux
http://www.fluxhome.com/products/Freewares/bittersweet2

StereoTools from Flux
http://www.fluxhome.com/products/Freewares/stereotool

bx_solo from Brainworx
http://www.brainworx-music.de/en/plugins/bx_solo

bx_cleansweep v2 from Brainworx
http://www.brainworx-music.de/en/plugins/bx_cleansweep_v2

Hope these help,

Mike.

ps.

After a little more research I found this page from MusicFormation.com
http://musformation.com/free-rtas-plugins.html

There is the SoundHack bundle as well
http://www.soundhack.com/freeware.php

Audio Geek Zine have a list of their top 10 which includes most of the above
http://www.audiogeekzine.com/2010/03/top-10-free-pro-tools-rtas-plugins/

and I wrote about some of them in Sound on Sound back in 2008
http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/feb08/articles/ptfeature_0208.htm

Answer (score 2):

Great links Mike.

Also, to answer the first part of the question, all RTAS plugins are compatible with BOTH PTLE and PTHD.

TDM and TDM-HD plugins are compatible only with PTHD.

Answer (score 1):

Try Massey [www.masseyplugins.com](http://www.masseyplugins.com).  They have a free unlimited demo period with no beeps.  The only problem with the demo is that it does not remember your settings (i.e. next time you start session your settings on the plugin will revert back to it's defaults).

I can't wait to dig into some of the items on Mike's list above.